# Export a video of a colored mesh

Tags: python, mesh, materials

I created an object from colored vertices using a mesh. My problem is that when I try to export an animation of this object as video, the color is gone. It seems to me that this is because my object didn't have a material attached to it. Then I added the a material, but the color is still not showing on export.
How can I transfer the color from vertices to the material?
Here is my code: everything is created by it from scratch.

```
import math

import bpy
import numpy as np


# Clear all
for o in bpy.data.objects:
    bpy.data.objects.remove(o, do_unlink=True)
for m in bpy.data.meshes:
    bpy.data.meshes.remove(m, do_unlink=True)
for m in bpy.data.materials:
    bpy.data.materials.remove(m, do_unlink=True)
for m in bpy.data.materials:
    bpy.data.materials.remove(m, do_unlink=True)
scene = bpy.context.scene


def f(a, b):
    return a**2 + b**2

def f_vect(ab):
    return f(a=ab[0], b=ab[1])


n_a = n_b = 100

a_vals = np.linspace(-5, 5, n_a)
b_vals = np.linspace(-5, 5, n_b)

all_ab_combos = np.dstack(np.meshgrid(a_vals, b_vals)).reshape(-1, 2)

f_vals = np.apply_along_axis(f_vect, 1, all_ab_combos)
min_f_val = np.min(np.min(f_vals))
max_f_val = np.max(np.max(f_vals))

# Create vertices
vertices = np.empty(n_a * n_b)
vertices[:] = np.nan
vertices = list(vertices)
occupied_indices = set()

for a_idx, a in enumerate(a_vals):
    for b_idx, b in enumerate(b_vals):
        v_idx = a_idx * n_b + b_idx
        assert np.isnan(vertices[v_idx])
        vertices[v_idx] = [a, b, f(a, b)]
        occupied_indices.add(v_idx)

# Create faces
faces = []
for a_idx in range(n_a - 1):
    for b_idx in range(n_b - 1):
        faces.append([a_idx * n_b + b_idx, a_idx * n_b + b_idx + 1, (a_idx + 1) * n_b + b_idx + 1,
                      (a_idx + 1) * n_b + b_idx])

# Create the surface
surf_name = "surf"
mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new(surf_name)
mesh.from_pydata(vertices, [], faces)

obj = bpy.data.objects.new(surf_name, mesh)
bpy.context.collection.objects.link(obj)

# Assign material
ob = obj

# Get material
mat = bpy.data.materials.get("Material")
if mat is None:
    # create material
    mat = bpy.data.materials.new(name="Material")

# Assign it to object
ob.data.materials.append(mat)

for f in mesh.polygons:
    f.use_smooth = True

# Generate vertex colors.
vc_layer = mesh.vertex_colors.new()
mn = 0.05
mx = 0.95
thresh1 = 0.4
thresh2 = 0.6

RED = np.array([1, 0, 0])
GREEN = np.array([0, 1, 0])
BLUE = np.array([0, 0, 1])
VIOLET = np.array([127, 0, 255]) / 255
CYAN = np.array([0, 1, 1])
MAGENTA = np.array([255, 0, 255]) / 255

color_templates = [MAGENTA, CYAN, BLUE, GREEN, RED, VIOLET]
thresholds = [0, 0.02, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 1]

for p in mesh.polygons:
    for idx in p.loop_indices:
        vi = mesh.loops[idx].vertex_index
        z_orig = mesh.vertices[vi].co[2]
        z = (z_orig - min_f_val) / (max_f_val - min_f_val)
        r = g = b = 0

        color = None

        prev_threshold_idx = None
        next_threshold_idx = None

        for th_idx, th in enumerate(thresholds):
            if th > z:
                next_threshold_idx = th_idx
                break

        if next_threshold_idx is None:  # z is above the highest threshold.
            color = color_templates[-1]
        else:
            prev_threshold_idx = next_threshold_idx - 1
            if prev_threshold_idx == -1:  # z is below the lowest threshold.
                color = color_templates[0]
            else:  # z is between to thresholds.
                th_prev = thresholds[prev_threshold_idx]
                th_next = thresholds[next_threshold_idx]
                alpha = (z - th_prev) / (th_next - th_prev)
                color = alpha * color_templates[next_threshold_idx] + (1 - alpha) * color_templates[prev_threshold_idx]
        assert color is not None

        r, g, b = list(color)
        assert 0 <= r <= 1
        assert 0 <= g <= 1
        assert 0 <= b <= 1
        vc_layer.data[idx].color[0] = r
        vc_layer.data[idx].color[1] = g
        vc_layer.data[idx].color[2] = b

# Get the reference to the active scene
scene = bpy.context.scene

# Create a new camera
camera = bpy.data.cameras.new("Camera")
camera_obj = bpy.data.objects.new("Camera", camera)
scene.collection.objects.link(camera_obj)
target_obj = bpy.data.objects[surf_name]
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = camera_obj
camera_obj.constraints.new(type='TRACK_TO')
camera_obj.constraints["Track To"].target = target_obj
camera_obj.constraints["Track To"].track_axis = 'TRACK_NEGATIVE_Z'
camera_obj.constraints["Track To"].up_axis = 'UP_Y'
camera_obj.location.z = 80

# Enable vertex paint view.
bpy.context.view_layer.update()
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
obj.select_set(True)
bpy.ops.paint.vertex_paint_toggle()

obj.rotation_euler = [0, 0, 0]
obj.keyframe_insert(data_path='rotation_euler', frame=1)
obj.rotation_euler = [0, 0, math.radians(90)]
obj.keyframe_insert(data_path='rotation_euler', frame=30)
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
mat.use_nodes = True
node_shader = mat.node_tree.nodes['Principled BSDF']
node_attr = mat.node_tree.nodes.new('ShaderNodeAttribute')
node_attr.attribute_name = vc_layer.name
mat.node_tree.links.new(node_attr.outputs[0], node_shader.inputs['Base Color'])
```

It feeds the vertex color (now called "attribute") into the shader. You can choose to instead feed the color directly into the output Surface socket, or use shader emission.
[image: nodes]

Alternatively / additionally, you can display vertex colors in Solid viewport mode without the need for a material.

```
for area in bpy.context.screen.areas: 
    if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
        for space in area.spaces: 
            if space.type == 'VIEW_3D' and space.shading.type == 'SOLID':
                space.shading.color_type = 'VERTEX'
```

In this case, you would have to render using Workbench as your engine.

[image: workbench]

Comment: Thanks, that solved it. Although my animations come out way darker than previews. Did it actually render for you with the bright colors shown in the image?

Comment: If you use the first method (simply connecting to base color), the object will be lit/shadowed by the world lighting, which is a grey void by default. Feed it directly to have it unaffected by lighting, or use the seconds method (Workbench with Flat shading).

Comment: Thanks! That worked.

Comment: Well, it made the rendered video brighter. Yet, the video that actually gets saved looks somehow washed up compared to what I see in the renderer. The colors are somehow less vibrant. I used high quality settings, which makes it strange.

Comment: Under Color Management, try [changing the view transform to Standard.](https://i.imgur.com/qASODtP.png)

Comment: Video encoding probably cuts off some color range, but [from what I'm seeing](https://imgur.com/a/badrq7I), things match up to a reasonable extent (all four in Workbench/Flat).

Comment: Changing the view to Standard did it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: So the animation works, but I was wondering how to now add a texture to the surface? Do I understand it right that with the current setup it won't be possible because we're using the Workbench engine? It seems to only work for me in previw, but when I export the animation to a file, the texture is gone together with the material

Comment: Workbench only allows either vertex colors, or a texture - not both. If something works in preview but not on render, maybe you didn't change the settings on the render tab? Mixing vertex color with a texture in Eevee/ Cycles would require a Mix Color node ( [like so](https://i.imgur.com/wwuFHGC.png) )